# find x given y of a fonction in python without library

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, max

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwSBg.jpg)for my exercise sheet, I need to write a function which find the x value for given y value of a function (called Maxwell_Boltzmann) without any library function. So I tried to define the function ( called most_probable_speed) which at first, find the maximum value of the y value of Maxwell_Boltzmann, and then find for which x (which is defined as v in my code), the maximum is reached. I did this with a for and if loop trying to print v, but it doesnt print me the parameter v for which the maximun is reached but gives me the entire vector v. Has anyone any idea how I could print the parameter v, for which y is reached ?

my code is:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy
import scipy.constants as cs

v= np.linspace(-100,10000,1000) #this are my x values


#this is my function, which prints y value in fonction of x
def Maxwell_Boltzmann(v, m, T):
      ''' calculate the Maxwell-Boltzmann  distribution
      for the speed of the chemical elements

      3 parameters: -the speed of the particle
              -its masse
              -its temperature'''
      y = np.sqrt(2/np.pi) * (m /( cs.k * T))**(3/2) * v**2 * np.exp(-m*v**2/(2 * cs.k * T)) 
      return y;




# this is the function which is suppose to find the x value given the y value
def most_probable_speed(v,m,T):
       '''determine the most probable speed of a given mass and temperature'''

       x = Maxwell_Boltzmann(v, m, T) #put the y values of Maxwel_B for all x in an array named x
       highest_probability = np.amax(x) #Return the maximum value of y


       # I want to print the value of v for whcih Maxwell_Boltzmann(v, m, T)= highest_probability
       for a in Maxwell_Boltzmann(v, m, T):
           if a == highest_probability:
               print(v)
           else:
               continue

return highest_probability;


m_oxy = 15.99 * cs.u 
most_probable_speed(v, m = m_oxy, T = 273)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since each element of y corresponds to the element of v in the same index (which is the x value you want), you can use `enumerate` to give you the index of each value and print out the corresponding `x` rather than the entire vector:

```
def most_probable_speed(v,m,T):
       '''determine the most probable speed of a given mass and temperature'''

       x = Maxwell_Boltzmann(v, m, T) #put the y values of Maxwel_B for all x in an array named x
       highest_probability = np.amax(x) #Return the maximum value of y


       # I want to print the value of v for whcih Maxwell_Boltzmann(v, m, T)= highest_probability
       for idx, a in enumerate(Maxwell_Boltzmann(v, m, T)):
           if a == highest_probability:
               print(v[idx])
           else:
               continue
```

However, you are calling the Maxwell_Boltzmann function twice. If you simply want to find the x corresponding to the highest y value, you can do this much more efficiently like this:

```
def most_probable_speed(v,m,T):
       '''determine the most probable speed of a given mass and temperature'''

       x = Maxwell_Boltzmann(v, m, T) #put the y values of Maxwel_B for all x in an array named x
       highest_probability_idx = np.argmax(x) # Return the index of the maximum value of y
       print(v[highest_probability_idx])
```

Here, [`np.argmax`](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.argmax.html) returns the index of the maximum value in your returned array, which you can then use to access the corresponding x in your `v` vector

Comment: @user11659631 no problem

Comment: Thanks for the edit! I look into it, it's always really nice to see how the easiest way works.

Comment: @user11659631 of course and yeah numpy has a lot of cool functions you can use to do things more efficiently - I'm still learning about most of them

Comment: yeah exactly, and you need other people to show it to you sometimes ahah